# bash double-quotes behavior with array values

Tags: arrays, bash, double-quotes

I have this input file

```
first line
second line
wow! something
the last line
```

I fill an array with the lines with the "line" word whit this script

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS_backup=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'  
lines=($(grep "line" "$1")) 
IFS=IFS_backup

i=0
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
  echo $line
  echo "$line"
done
```

I get this output

```
first line
first line
se ond line
second line
the l st line
the last line
```

What's happening here? I supposed the quotes will bound the words togheter, creating a string. Here the missing quotes leads to missing random characters...

Thanks!

NOTE: I KNOW that there are other ways fill an array with file lines. By the way, this is just an example; my actual array is filled in a more tricky way, but the quotes behaviour is the same. I will like to know why THIS script have the desriced bahavior.

Comment: use `IFS="$IFS_backup"` (note the `$`)

Comment: Damn... Thanks for spotting my (dumb) error. Well, functionality aside, what's happening when the IFS is wrong?

Comment: individual characters in `IFS_backup` act as `IFS`. so `echo second line` is treated as `echo "se" "ond line"`, instead of your expectation - `echo "second" "line"`.

Comment: So, since IFS is set to the string "IFS_backup", does it mean that strings are separated when any of the characters in "IFS_backup" is found? Seems so from the example: "se-c-ond string" "the l-a-st line". So the string "Fourth line in file" will be split echoed as " o rth line  N file". Did I get it? EDIT: well, I testes it and it behave like this. I think I got it.

Comment: yes. for the `Fourth line in file` will get ` o rth line in file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an wrong IFS value. You need

```
IFS="$IFS_backup"
```

instead of

```
IFS=IFS_backup
```

in your case, the field separator contains characters `IFS_backup`

demo:

```
lines=($(seq 1020 1080))
IFS='246'   # <-- the input field separator now any of the characters 2 or 4 or 6
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
  echo $line
done
```

prints

```
10 0
10 1
10 
10 3
10 
10 5
10 
10 7
10 8
10 9
1030
1031
103
1033
103
1035
103
1037
1038
1039
10 0
10 1
10 
10 3
10 
10 5
10 
10 7
10 8
10 9
1050
1051
105
1053
105
1055
105
1057
1058
1059
10 0
10 1
10 
10 3
10 
10 5
10 
10 7
10 8
10 9
1070
1071
107
1073
107
1075
107
1077
1078
1079
1080
```

or even better demo

```
#!/bin/bash

showargs() {
    i=0
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        let i++
        echo "got arg $i:==$arg=="
    done

    i=0
    for arg in "$*"
    do
        let i++
        echo "print using the 1st char from IFS - got arg $i:==$arg=="
    done
}

lines=(1233 12469 1469)
IFS='246'
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
    echo "============$line=============="
    showargs $line
done
```

prints

```
============1233==============
got arg 1:==1==
got arg 2:==33==
print using the 1st char from IFS - got arg 1:==1233==
============12469==============
got arg 1:==1==
got arg 2:====
got arg 3:====
got arg 4:==9==
print using the 1st char from IFS - got arg 1:==12229==
============1469==============
got arg 1:==1==
got arg 2:====
got arg 3:==9==
print using the 1st char from IFS - got arg 1:==1229==
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I made further tests myself to better understand it (see comments on my question).

Comment: @il_mix The preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by accepting the most helpful answer (click on the green checkmark) to any question you ask (which also increases a bit your reputation too), and by up-voting helpful answers (if you have 15+ reputation).  Please read the [tour], and good luck with the answers.

Comment: Well... didn't check the "correct answer" since I've understand the problem by Q&A in the comments section of my question. Btw, marked.